# How to show pages when user press button?

Tags: silverlight

I've got 4 pages. I want to open 3 other pages when I press button on the current page.

But the pages don't have show method. How to open them?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Navigation Application, you must have a ContentFrame in your MainPage.xaml.

You have to load your pages in that ContentFrame to will show your pages.  The ContentFrame has a Navigate method to allow you to load pages into it.

You can also use the "NavigationService.Navigate()" to navigate through your pages, that method don't need a reference to your ContentFrame.

Comment: I've got Silverlight application ASP.net WEb site. and I add page with "Add new item->Silverlight page"

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve here.  The buttons you are talking about, are they ASP.NET or Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(link), "_blank");` to open a URI in a new tab.